# How to add a specific part of an image in pygame?

Tags: pygame, pygame-surface

I want to load a specific part of an image in pygame. 
How do I do it?
I have an image of a character in different angles. In SDL we use a rect, but do we have this option in pygame?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I crop an image with Pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239769/how-can-i-crop-an-image-with-pygame)

Comment: You can also use the [`pygame.Surface.subsurface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.subsurface) method, but have to make sure that the rect is inside of the image area.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit 
use the surface.blit(source, dest, area=None, special_flags = 0)). the area argument will allow you to put a rect of what part of the image that you want to draw