# Problem with alpha channels in my picture (PyGame)

Tags: python, pygame

Currently, I'm trying to paste a picture to my pygame game and this picture have a alpha channel (as you can see bellow this sentence).

[Original Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQh6R.jpg)

But, for some reason, when I use `convert()` or `convert_alpha()`, it's not putting correctly the picture with the alpha channel on the game... Even when I tried to do some mainpulations of the picture, nothing.

[What happened (with the manipulations)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnfLt.png)

Here is the code I tried to write (with the manipulations for alpha channel that it didn't worked) :

```
class Spritesheet:
    # utility class for loading and parsing spritesheets
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.spritesheet = pygame.image.load(filename).convert()

    def get_image(self, x, y, width, height):
        # grab an image out of a larger spritesheet
        image = pygame.Surface((width, height))
        image.fill(pygame.color.Color("black"))
        image.blit(self.spritesheet, (0, 0), (x, y, width, height))
        image.set_colorkey(pygame.color.Color("black"))
        return image
```

How can I put a picture who have originally the alpha channel on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that image has a transparency information. If the background isn't transparent, you can't magically get it (except the background has a uniform color). See [Pygame image transparency confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64704789/pygame-image-transparency-confusion/64704923#64704923)

---

You have to use [`convert_alpha`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert_alpha) instead of [`convert`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert):

<s>`self.spritesheet = pygame.image.load(filename).convert()`</s>

```py
self.spritesheet = pygame.image.load(filename).convert_alpha()
```

Use [`convert_alpha()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert_alpha) to create a copy of the *Surface* with an image format that provides alpha per pixel. When using `convert`, the alpha channel and the transparency of the image is lost.

Additionally create a *Surface* with a per pixel alpha format. Set the [`SRCALPHA`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) flag to create a surface with an image format that includes a per-pixel alpha:

<s>`image = pygame.Surface((width, height))`</s>

```py
image = pygame.Surface((width, height), pygame.SRCALPHA)
```

```py
class Spritesheet:
    # utility class for loading and parsing spritesheets
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.spritesheet = pygame.image.load(filename).convert_alpha()

    def get_image(self, x, y, width, height):
        # grab an image out of a larger spritesheet
        image = pygame.Surface((width, height), pygame.SRCALPHA)
        image.fill(pygame.color.Color("black"))
        image.blit(self.spritesheet, (0, 0), (x, y, width, height))
        return image
```

---

Alternatively you can create a sub-surface with [`pygame.Surface.subsurface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.subsurface). See [How can I crop an image with Pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239769/how-can-i-crop-an-image-with-pygame/65627793#65627793).

```py
class Spritesheet:
    # utility class for loading and parsing spritesheets
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.spritesheet = pygame.image.load(filename).convert_alpha()

    def get_image(self, x, y, width, height):
        return image.subsurface(pygame.Rect(x, y, width, height))
```

Comment: The problem of making the `convert_alpha()` is that it's making the same thing of the second picture that I posted.